# SQL Server Asp.Net - "Login failed"

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I can't get my Asp.Net application to work on a server I'm deploying to. The server is running Server 2008 R2, and I am running SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on top of that. When I browse to the site I get error

> Login failed for user 'WIN-6VLI5UDJ5RN\Lappearn'

I have tried creating the account both in SQL Server and on the server itself but made no difference. Here is my connection string

```
Data Source=localhost\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Lappearn;User ID=WIN-6VLI5UDJ5RN\Lappearn;Password=password;
```

The SQL Server is now running both Windows and SQL Server auth mode.

Comment: Perhaps there is a typo in your username? Lappearn or AppLearn?

Comment: Actually i forgot to change the username and passwords before posting here :S

Comment: The username and the database name are the same?  That might not be a good idea, just from a command parsing perspective.  Either way, the login is simply failing.  Check the permissions on the SQL server.  Maybe that user can't access that database?  Maybe there's a SQL user named `Lappearn` instead of a Windows user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To enable a user, you have to set them up on the database AND grant permissions to them on the database and/or its tables and stored procedures.

It sounds like you have created the user account or login. You have to also grant that user permissions on the database. This is often done by assigning the user to an existing group with permissions, such as `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter`.

Here is one set of [step-by-step instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998292.aspx) on how to set up your database permissions, and [here's one for SQL 2008 and IIS7](http://evonet.com.au/setting-up-sql-server-2008-for-an-asp-net-website-on-iis-7-0/).

Comment: I tried using the format of the ConnectionStrings in that guide, and then it tries to use account 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0' instead, because then i get error "Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0'.". That account doesn't seem to exist neither in Windows or SQL Server

Comment: You need to set the permissions on the database for whichever user you want to use. There is more than one step involved. You have to set up the user AND grant permissions for that user. Your problem is not in your connection string.

Comment: I was able to solve it, changed the account of the AppPool to one which has credentials to access the SQL server :) Thank you for your help!

Comment: There you go! It's kind of a complicated process, and hard to remember, because we do it so rarely -- only when we first start working on a new app.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a fresh installation of SQL Server Express make sure you have enabled 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode' in server Properties->Security. The default is 'Windows Authentication Mode'. Then restart the SQL Server. This worked for me!

No matter what you try, you will not be able to log in with a SQL user in Windows mode.