# Hosting project on IIS - connection string issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, iis

I have published my .Net Core app to IIS. It is task manager.
Title page works fine, but when I open tasks page, where it make request to the database, it show me this error (even in Development mode).

I think it is something wrong with connection string.
It work fine when I launch it from Visual Studio.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the database on the same computer as IIS? If so, use `.Server=.\SQLEXPRESS` and make sure that the application pool identity that the site runs under is allowed to log in to the database (and that everything that username needs to access - tables, stored procedures, anything else - has the correct permissions): [SQL Server Asp.Net - "Login failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8804793/1115360).

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 There are too many fundamental differences you should be aware of.

Comment: `"Title page works fine, but when I open tasks page, where it make request to the database"` did you had the chance to set debugpointer on that `title page database context` is that executing or not? Does the database connection traced connectly?